# chata application built in jquery - how to keep client & server connected

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i have built a jquery based text chat in asp.net..... the flow is as such...
User A logs in.... Now in the bottom of my page i have a iframe on which the jquery code is embedded.. the jquery will send request to server after every 5 seconds... on the server i have a web method that will check the if any user has sent a text message to user A (checks in database).. if found it will return it in json format and will be displayed in a div...
my problem is that is it a good idea to send request to server after every 5 seconds... suppose 1000s of users gets logged in.. jquery will send 1000s of request every 5 seconds... i am new i need your support

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking on client side by sending request to server each 5 seconds; let server sends a message when receives a message concerning any user.

Comment: how will server communicate with client then... client will definitely have to stay connected with server to get such a message.. remember http is a stateless protocol..

Comment: i just read somewhere comet and pokein are good tools.. has anyone worked with it...

Comment: See this implementation. [link](http://communication.howstuffworks.com/instant-messaging2.htm)

Comment: wht about wcf duplex service... has any one worked on it... wil it provide me any solution